# Can not add WebLogic to NetBeans. Add WebLogic server dialog does not accept the provided path

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic, java-ee-8

**Context**

I just installed WebLogic development server 14.1.1.0.0  (using `fmw_14.1.1.0.0_wls_lite_quick_generic.jar`) The server is up and running, with the single default local base_domain.

I've also installed NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) running on Java: 1.8.0_211; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.211-b12.

I am trying to add and configure WebLogic Server but NetBeans does not accept the provided path.
For some paths the error message is

> The entered installation is not properly structured,

which is OK, but for the correct path,  the message is

> Please enter Oracle WebLogic Server installation directory

and the Next button is disabled.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Many other paths within the Oracle folder, but I think the folder wlserver should be the correct
- Changing all backslashes to slashes
- Adding removing the slash at the end of the path.
- Checking persmissions. The user running NetBeans have full access to the folders
- Stoppig WebLogic and try in this stopped state

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not that it helps you at all, but I just tried installing WebLogic 14 on NB 8.2 on Windows 10, and hit exactly the same problems as you. I don't see that you are doing anything wrong. One additional thing I tried was to start NetBeans using _Run As Administrator_ but that didn't help either. Consider checking the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) to see if there are any unexpected errors/stack traces during the WebLogic configuration process, and if so then update your question accordingly, You could also try deleting your cache directory and retrying, but that's a sign of desperation!

Comment: If you go to the [System Requirements and Supported Platforms for Oracle WebLogic Server 14c](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/fusion-certification.html) it links to an XLS spreadsheet. If you open that spreadsheet it states that WebLogic 14 requires **Oracle JDK 1.8.0_251 or later** on Windows, so make sure that you are doing that. I'm not sure whether the JDK for WebLogic can be distinct from the one used by NetBeans, but since you definitely need to specify an Oracle JDK for WebLogic you might as well specify that same JDK for NetBeans 8.2.

Comment: Even the simplest things, what we've done zillion times stops working suddenly. Probably either I degrade to WebLogic 12.x or I launch a Linux VM... btw delete *which* cache, where?

Comment: [1] **Help > About** specifies the _Cache Directory_ for NetBeans. To clear it: note its full path name, close NetBeans, delete that directory (or just rename it if you feel wary), and then start NetBeans. Done! [2] More importantly though, you really need to be using a valid (i.e. supported) JDK for WebLogic 14. See [Restricting Incoming Serialized Java Objects to Oracle WebLogic Server](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2421487_1.html) for more details. [3] Is it feasible to use a more recent version of NetBeans, or are you tied to 8.2?

Comment: NetBeans log has no errors. Meanwhile I've updated to java version "1.8.0_301". Reconfiguring WebLogic seems to be error prone, as the old JAVA_HOME hardcodes to the shell files dozen times, so I choose wipe it up and reinstall/reconfigure. Same issue as before. Anyway, I think the folder should be recognized by NetBeans while wlserver not even running, so the error is somewhere else. Maybe this function never worked on Windows...

Comment: Using wls 12.x all works...